# Get averages from array of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of arrays similar to this:

```
[["Timmy", "90", "47", "89"], ["Simon", "89", "57", "99"]] (etc)
```

I need to go through each sub-array and total up the numbers in each and give the average of each subarray.

I'm not sure how I would go about accessing each number. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The average of the numbers in each subarray, or the average over all subarrays?

Comment: The average of the numbers in each subarray. Sorry!

Comment: Why does this sound like homework?

Comment: @theTinMan, it was a small sub section of a homework I was doing. Reading in from a CSV files gave me an array with subarrays which we'd never worked with. Rather than posting my whole assignment I asked for help with just reading over the array and then creating a new array. You know, sometimes people such as yourself get a little too worked up on SO. The answer I got not only explained how everything worked, but introduced me to several new things in Ruby I've never worked with. I learned much more than I would've on my own. Ex map, map!, inject , etc.

Comment: You don't know me, nor do you know if I get worked up. You might want to read "[Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)". You'd find it very interesting reading and it will give you an understanding why a lot of people want disclosure of homework questions and might possibly not want to help answer them. Here are a number of [other questions regarding homework](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework).

Comment: Your comment just sounded rather condescending when I read it. That's all. However, like I said, this was a rather small sub-section of what I was working on. When your professors are not available to help you SO is an incredible resource. The community here is incredible and they not only help with the answer, they teach and explain what is going on. The answer I received here was incredible and it taught me a lot. Your comment caught me at a bad time and I reacted rather immaturely to it so for that I apologize. I just become peeved when I ask for help with a concept not the answer for hw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
arr = [["Timmy", "90", "47", "89"], ["Simon", "89", "57", "99"]]
averages = arr.map do |name, *nums|
  [name, nums.map(&:to_f).inject(:+) / nums.length]
end
# => [["Timmy", 75.33333333333333], ["Simon", 81.66666666666667]]
```

This solution uses ruby's list comprehension, so for each element in `arr` is run on the block with parameters `|name, *nums|`, `name` is set to the first element in the array, and `nums` is set to the rest of the array (minus `name`).

`nums.map(&:to_f).inject(:+)` turns each string to a floating point number, which is then divided by the number of elements in `nums` to create the average.

Comment: It's hard to improve on this, except possible adding `.round(2)` :-). If you didn't know where poor Timmy is in the array you could just change `[name, *nums|` to  |*nums|`. Ah, yes, and change to `nums.lenght-1`, as you say.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - if you didn't know where the name is, but you did know there _was_ a name (somewhere) in the array, you could do something like `nums.map(&:to_f).inject(:+) / (nums.length - 1)`, since `"Timmy".to_f` will be evaluated to `0.0`...

Comment: After doing a puts of arr after this block, I'm still getting the original array. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Destiny `map` does not change the original array. I've mended my answer to assign the result to a new variable (`averages`). If you want to change the original array - use [`map!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-map-21) instead of `map`

Answer (score 0):

A bit different and a slightly faster variant:

```
arr = [["Timmy", "90", "47", "89"], ["Simon", "89", "57", "99"]]
averages = arr.map do |name, *nums|
  [name, nums.inject(0){|acc, el| acc + el.to_f} / nums.length]
end
p averages
# => [["Timmy", 75.33333333333333], ["Simon", 81.66666666666667]]
```

Uses `inject` with accumulator which initially is 0. Then add to it each num converted to Float.

Benchmarking:

```
require 'benchmark'
arr = [["Timmy", "90", "47", "89"], ["Simon", "89", "57", "99"]]
n = 1_000_000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("map.inject : ") { n.times do ; arr.map do |name, *nums| ; [name, nums.map(&:to_f).inject(:+) / nums.length] ; end ; end }
  x.report("inject(acc): ") { n.times do ; arr.map do |name, *nums|; [name, nums.inject(0){|ac,el| ac +el.to_f} / nums.length]; end ; end }
end

#=>       user     system      total        real
#=> map.inject :   2.220000   0.000000   2.220000 (  2.218477)
#=> inject(acc):   2.030000   0.000000   2.030000 (  2.031263)
```